# Does Mark 2:21-22 mean that we don't need to obey Old Testament Laws?

Tags: exegesis, mosaic-law, gospel-of-mark

Jesus said:

[Mark 2:21-22 (NLT)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%202%3A21-22&version=NLT)

> “Besides, who would patch old clothing with new cloth? For the new patch would shrink and rip away from the old cloth, leaving an even bigger tear than before.  And no one puts new wine into old wineskins. For the wine would burst the wineskins, and the wine and the skins would both be lost. New wine calls for new wineskins.”

Can we interpret those verses to mean that we only need to concentrate on the New Testament and ignore the laws in the Old Testament?  Even the 10 commandments are reduced to just two commands in new testament.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're asking - could you edit to make it a bit clearer? Additionally, could you please include what perspective you're seeking - general bible interpretation questions without specifying a particular denominational or doctrinal framework are actually off-topic here. Refer to our [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) for more info on this.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  I've attempted to help you out by correcting some of the wording of your question which was making it difficult to understand.  Hopefully I kept it true to your original intent.  If not, feel free to edit it again to make your intentions more plain.  However, even with my corrections, the question is still not a great fit for this site.  This site is not intended to be used to debate or discuss what the correct interpretation of scripture is.

Comment: Your question would be more on topic if it were asking for which denominations hold to that view, or what other verses are used by people to support that view, or whether or not that view has an official doctrinal name by which it can be referenced, or if you were even asking for an overview of a list of all the most common ways in which these verses are interpreted by different groups (although that's pushing it as being a bit too broad).

Comment: Take note of David Stratton's last comment on that question to which @curiousdannii linked.  It was a highly rated question at the time that it was posted, but the purpose of the site has since been narrowed considerably so such questions are no longer considered to be on topic.  Please don't take any criticism of your first question in a negative way.  I'm just trying to help you learn the ropes.  It's a very good question, just not a great fit for the site.  Hopefully we'll see you around more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Even though as bruised reed, stated your question is not directed at any specific denomination, and as such becomes a truth question, I feel compelled to answer your question since it, points out a common problem encountered when reading the Bible. Many Scriptures taken alone are at best confusing and at worst misleading. Your question appears to be spawned in that category.

Lets take a look at those Scriptures you quoted and see what other Scriptures can help us understand what they refer to.

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation, unless otherwise noted.

> Mark 2:21 and 22  No man also seweth a piece of new cloth on an old garment: else the new piece that filled it up taketh away from the old, and the rent is made worse. 22  And no man putteth new wine into old bottles: else the new wine doth burst the bottles, and the wine is spilled, and the bottles will be marred: but new wine must be put into new bottles.

When we also consider that Jesus was answering this specific question:

> Mar 2:18  And the disciples of John and of the Pharisees used to fast: and they come and say unto him, Why do the disciples of John and of the Pharisees fast, but thy disciples fast not?

and that he prefaced the Scriptures quoted in your question with:

> Mark 2:19 and 20  And Jesus said unto them, Can the children of the bridechamber fast, while the bridegroom is with them? as long as they have the bridegroom with them, they cannot fast. 20  But the days will come, when the bridegroom shall be taken away from them, and then shall they fast in those days.

We are then being directed to a specific train of thought which is that there is something much more important in that hearing what Jesus has to say; is much more important than how it is to be enacted, after his departure. Or put another way he is telling them that before they can instruct others they must themselves have the whole story. This is emphasized by verses 19 and 20.

Now we can analyze the last Scriptures in this diatribe, with a clearer understanding.

Verse 21 and 22 are used as an illustration which they would be familiar with, that being that when an un-shrunk fabric or animal skin (Goat skin was used to fabricate wineskins)
is inserted into already shrunken cloth or skins would as it shrank; instead of repairing, further ruin the old.

Why this is important to understand can be best illustrated by considering that without his resurrection, his death would have no impact. It is only his taking up his life after, everyone knew that he had died, which gives meaning to his promise of eternal life.

The proper attitude toward how the Old Testament is to be viewed in relation to the New Testament is in the following Scriptures:

> Matthew 5:17and 18  Think not that I am come to destroy the law, or the prophets: I am not come to destroy, but to fulfil. 18  For verily I say unto you, Till heaven and earth pass, one jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass from the law, till all be fulfilled.

In these two Scriptures we are taught that:

1. The laws of God given in the Old Testament will always be in effect until:

> Revelation 21:1  And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea.

2. That Jesus came to the Earth expressly to fulfill those requirements laid down by God, because we could not live up to Gods standards, but he could.

Hope this helps.